# citus add node --> "fe_sendauth: no password supplied" error

Tags: django, postgresql, sharding, citus

I am trying to setup multi node schema based sharding for postgresql database using citus extension.

I have two azure virtual machines , one is working as worker node('20.40.43.246') and other as coordinator ('20.198.17.232')

I am following this documention https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/installation/multi_node_debian.html#steps-to-be-executed-on-all-nodes

On worker node database is set up and it is running fine.

on coordiator node when i run `sudo -i -u postgres psql -c  "SELECT * from citus_add_node('20.40.43.246', 5432);"` I am getting below error.

```
ERROR:  connection to the remote node 20.40.43.246:5432 failed with the following error: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

What configuration do i need to change in pb_hba.conf on worker node?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to add 20.40.43.246 to the pg_hba instead of the 10.* which that link shows.  But I would worry that maybe the IP address will get assigned to someone else someday, who would then have access to your system. Since Citus is owned by Microsoft now, its seems like you might be able to find some Azure-specific instructions.

Also, your hba must have some lines besides the one shown at that link, otherwise you would not be getting that error message.